# Basic PHP contact form redirect to sucess page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the attached contact form PHP script working but I would like the form to redirect to a sucess page: /form-confirmation.php

http://www.frlaw.co.uk/Contact-Test.php

Hope you can help.
Rich

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
  $email_to = "sales@adelantedesign.co.uk";
  $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

  function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
  }

  // validation expected data exists

  if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['telephone']) || !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
  }

  $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
  $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
  $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
  $error_message = "";
  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

  $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

  function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }

  $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
  <!-- include your own success html here -->
  Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: "died()" is no php function. The right syntax is "die()"

Comment: Is PHP function [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect in a php by using the following lines:

```
header('Location: form-confirmation.php');
exit();
```

However you must do this before the page headers are sent (before any content is rendered on the page).

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript so that you can also put a timer delay on it so that people will see your Thank you message.

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = 'form-confirmation.php';
  }, 5000); //5 seconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the browser to redirect to a certain page by using PHP `header()`

So, if the mail is accepted for delivery then redirect the user to `form-confirmation`:

```
if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
   header("Location: form-confirmation.php");
   exit;
}
```